# How do I make/get a odometer for a lunch box sized robot?

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics

Say I have given the robot a map of the place, it needs to navigate it. I need a odometer to keep track of its current position in the map. I need it to be precise up to a cm.

Can I simply use the motor's RPM and the diameter of the wheel to calculate how much distance the robot has travelled, or is there any catch?

I searched Google and could not find any odometer small enough for my robot. Most of them are for bicycles.

Comment: Seems to work pretty well here: https://youtu.be/tZ3fpZFWHDM?t=453 (7:33)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the idea to use a computer mouse (optical) to do this - cheap, easily available. You would need two, if you want to be able to measure turning rate, one on the left and one on the right.

You don't even need the whole mouse - if you pull it apart you can ditch the case, the buttons, and about half the circuitry. You will need to do some hacking to figure out how it works, but I doubt you'll find a cheaper odometer that is anywhere near as accurate.

Note: I pulled one apart, then got distracted on another project, but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is brilliant! If I had 15 reputation I would have given a thumbs up.

Comment: Good idea. Saves using a wheel at all. :)

Comment: Would this be tracking the ground the same way your mouse tracks the desk in order to move the cursor?

Comment: Yes, tracking the ground. I don't know how it would work on uneven surfaces - the lens of a mouse is a little way off the desk, there doesn't seem to be more than 1mm leeway in that.

Comment: The circuitry for controlling this might be difficult. I've used photointerrupters with tabs on an axle to track RPM, but that doesn't account for slippage it's true. Dead reckoning is always tricky!

Answer (score 0):

I think the catch is that the wheel will slip, particularly when starting up. The slightest slip and you are counting a rotation that didn't move the robot forwards. Also if it skids when stopping that is more movement that you didn't detect.

You are probably best off with a non-powered wheel (stuck out the side perhaps?) which has the task of only detecting movement. Perhaps put a rubber tire on it to get a good grip. You could connect a rotary encoder to the axle which could count the amount it has turned. There are rotary encoders which do not have friction (eg. optical or magnetic).

If the robot has some non-powered wheels (like a rear wheel) then that could be a good place to measure turns, as it wouldn't slip as much because it isn't under power. You might be able to detect the amount it has turned, for example if it had suitable holes that you could shine a light-detector through.

Alternatively if the area is small enough use a distance sensor (like a sonar) but that probably wouldn't be accurate enough.

Comment: I am thinking of using a sonar to calibrate the odometer every half a minute or so. The robot will use a pair of landmarks to determine its position then reset the odometer.